# Python import issue when running file as __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

This is the directory structure of my project.

```
.
├── args_parser.py
├── driver.py
├── event.py
├── logs
├── main.py
├── requirements.txt
├── scrap_results
├── sites
│   │
│   ├── tentimes.py
    └──...
│   └── xpath
│       │
│       └──10times.json
└── utils.py
```

I'm trying to import class `Event`  from `events.py`  into `sites/tentimes.py`. All sites run through `main.py` .

```
# sites/tentimes.py
from event import Event
```

this file doesn't run standalone and throws `ImportError`, but it does work when I run it through `main.py`.

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there any way to run only `sites/tentimes.py`  as **`__main__`**?

Thank you so much. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions to this problem. If the project is large enough that it needs subfolders, then I prefer the route of turning it into a python **package**. Then I install the package locally, using `python -m pip install -e .` When you do that and switch to absolute imports, they will work whether you run main.py or the submodule directly.

Here's an excellent article on the topic:
https://realpython.com/python-import/#create-and-install-a-local-package

Comment: Thanks for reply. The project is not that large. Is there any other way around it then installing it as a package?

Comment: @HarshRao the size doesn' really matter, you should package your project and pip-install it, perhaps in editable mode, to make things work right. Otherwise, you need to somehow get the appropriate path into the import path, e.g. using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or (worse) mess with `sys.path`

Comment: You could also just put all the files into the same folder.

Comment: @kevinzehnder Yeah, that's what I did temporarily. Will see try to install it as package when the code is ready. because both files are changing alot. I was just looking if anything else was possible.